# What is the basic concept of positive and negative charge of an atom?

Tags: quantum-chemistry

In ionic compounds, e.g. NaCl, chlorine 'steals' one electron from sodium. Because of this, sodium's proton number is increased by one, and the number of electrons in chlorine is increased by one. This makes sodium positively charged and chlorine negatively charged; opposite charges makes them attract to each other.

My question is that the nucleus of the sodium ion is still surrounded by electrons, and so does the nucleus of chlorine. Do those electrons repel, even though we say opposite charges attract? What do the electrons do while they attract?

Comment: Please don't edit your question to ask more questions. Also, 'core electrons' is an ambiguous term. In a sodium atom, there's only 1 valence electron. But in a sodium ion, there's 8; those 8 electrons which are now valence electrons were the 'core electrons' in the sodium atom. Refer to them as just 'electrons' for this sake to avoid confusion.

Comment: Basically you are asking if someone would be so nice to give you a comprehensive introduction to quantum mechanics for chemical compounds. While one should encourage people asking questions like you do, it's a bit much to ask. If you are really interested, there are entire libraries written on that topic. I'm sure your teacher (or whatever) will give you literature if you ask him/her nicely

Answer (score 6):

Sodium's proton number doesn't change else it'd become a different element.

In basic terms, sodium donates an electron to chlorine's outer electron shell; there is no electron 'stealing'. As much as both ions' nuclei are surrounded by electrons, the charges of the ions are based on the ratio of protons to electrons. For example, in an atom, the number of protons and electrons are equal to give no overall charge.

However, in an ion it's different; the sodium ion has 11 protons but only 10 electrons, so has a relative charge of 1<sup>+</sup>, as there's one more positive charge (proton) than there are negative charges (electrons). On the flip side, the chloride ion has 17 protons and 18 electrons, so has a relative charge of 1<sup>-</sup>, as there's one more negative charge than there are positive charges.

This then causes the electrostatic attraction between the two ions, which we call ionic bonding.

Comment: IMHO, the transfer of electron can be described as stealing all right.

Comment: @Ivan Neretin Meh. I don't really like to imagine atoms 'stealing' electrons from other atoms... Whatever works for us.

Comment: The first ionization energy (the minimum energy required to eject an electron out of a neutral atom in its ground state) of sodium is about 496 kJ/mol; therefore, sodium is not donating its electron voluntarily. However, it’s also not chlorine that is stealing the electron since the first electron affinity (the energy released when an additional electron is attached to a neutral atom) of chlorine is only 349 kJ/mol and thus not enough to steal the electron from sodium. It’s actually the large lattice energy of NaCl that provides the energy for its formation.

Comment: @Loong I was going to talk about ionisation energies and electron affinities but I decided to keep it simple.

Answer (score 0):

The overall, or so to speak average charge of an ion is what attracts an ion of opposite charge.

The electrons within an atom do repel each other alright. That is why the electron hull is not a uniform structure but consists of so called orbitals allowing the electrons to distribute themselves with maximum distance to each other.

Besides the electric charge the electron has another property called spin. Electrons with different spin can occupy the same spot in spacetime. Electrons with same spin repel each other. This is why electrons inhabit oribtals pairwise.

In your example $\ce{NaCl}$ the orbitals just align so perfectly that the attracting Sodium and Chloride ions fit into a very dense grid. But not denser, because, as you said, the electron hulls repel each other.

Comment: I want to add that what I explained above is just a model of the reality. A model that happens to describe the phaenomena at hand well enough and to be academically accepted.
My chemistry teacher in school used to hold up a matchbox car and to say
"This is not a car. It's a model of one".